# Riemann Stieltjes Integration by Parts on RCLL functions

Tags: riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I have the following integral that I am trying to evaluate with integration by parts.

$\int_{[0,T]} P_{t^{-}} d\gamma_t$

Where $P_{t^{-}}$ is the left limit of $P_t$ for a simple random walk,

$dP_t= \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$

And a function consisting of the difference of two non-decreasing, Right-Continuous functions with Left Limits,

$\gamma_t = \gamma_t^{+} - \gamma_t^{-}$

I have having a difficult time understanding how I should treat Integration by Parts with these RCLL functions. According to 3.12 on http://math4tune.com/stats%205-11-2007.pdf (page 33), I can express my integral as:

$ \int_{[0,T] } P_{t^{-}} d\gamma_t = P_T \gamma_T - P_0\gamma_0 - \int_{[0,T] } \gamma_{t} dP_t$

However, this goes against what I intuitively think is correct:
Might the following work?

$ \int_{[0,T] } P_{t^{-}} d\gamma_t = P_{T^{-}} \gamma_{T^{-}} - P_{0^{-}}\gamma_{0^{-}} - \int_{[0,T] } \gamma_{t^{-}} dP_t$

Conceptually, how should I be thinking about this kind of Integration by Parts?

Thanks!

M